# I'm getting column '. as col_2_0_' in JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm having this confusing problem trying to query @OneToMany relationship using JPA `CriteriaQuery` where there's this columns named `. as col_2_0_` (notice the dot), there's nothing but a dot in that column. And obviously, an expcetion is being thrown:
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. as col_2_0_, stockdetai1_.id as id1_6_, stockdetai1_.active as active2_6_, sto' at line 1`
Here are the mappings

Product.class

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ProductIdGenerator.NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = ProductIdGenerator.NAME, strategy = ProductIdGenerator.PATH)
    @Column(updatable = false, length = IDENTIFIER_LENGTH, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(11)")
    private String id;
    // other columns

    //-----------problem here-----------//
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<StockDetail> stockDetails;
    //----------------------------------//

    // getters and setters
}
```

StockDetail.class

```
public class StockDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = StockDetailIdGenerator.NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = StockDetailIdGenerator.NAME, strategy = StockDetailIdGenerator.PATH)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)", updatable = false)
    private String id;

    //---------here's the foreign key---------//
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product product;
    //---------here's the foreign key---------//
    // other columns
    // getters and setters
}
```

Here's the query

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<E> root = query.from(type);

query = selectColumns(query, root, columns).where(builder.and(isActive(builder, root),
    builder.equal(root.get(HibernateHelper.getIdentifierPropertyName(type)), id)));

return session.createQuery(query).getResultStream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Here's Hibernate query logging

```
Hibernate: 
select
    product0_.active as col_0_0_,
    product0_.name as col_1_0_,
    . as col_2_0_, // unknown column
    stockdetai1_.id as id1_6_,
    stockdetai1_.active as active2_6_,
    stockdetai1_.color as color3_6_,
    stockdetai1_.description as descript4_6_,
    stockdetai1_.material as material5_6_,
    stockdetai1_.numeric_size as numeric_6_6_,
    stockdetai1_.product_id as product10_6_,
    stockdetai1_.provider_id as provide11_6_,
    stockdetai1_.size as size7_6_,
    stockdetai1_.sold_by as sold_by12_6_,
    stockdetai1_.status as status8_6_,
    stockdetai1_.stocked_by as stocked13_6_,
    stockdetai1_.stocked_date as stocked_9_6_ 
from
    products product0_ 
inner join
    stock_details stockdetai1_ 
        on product0_.id=stockdetai1_.product_id 
where
    product0_.active=1 
    and product0_.id=?
```

DB schema

[image]

I've checked the requested colunms to see if there was any unwanted/unknown/unusual columns but they were all clean. The exception was only thrown from the `DBMS`, not the `ORM`.
I really don't want to separately fetch the `StockDetail` using another query. Thank you for any help guys.

Comment: Can you show the DB schema? Also, please delete most of the other columns - they are irrelevant to your problem and including them in your question only adds clutter.

Comment: We see it's generating a bad native query, but what about the JPQL query? Save `session.createQuery(query)` as a `org.hibernate.query.Query` and call `getQueryString()` on it to get the JPQL query, and log it. Also if the bug is not in Hibernate, then it's somewhere in those `// other columns` that you've skipped on.

Comment: @coladict Hi, `select generatedAlias0.active, generatedAlias0.name, generatedAlias0.stockDetails from Product as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.active = true ) and ( generatedAlias0.id=:param0 )` here's the JPQL query that you're talking about, and I honestly could not spot any fraud.

Comment: Are you sure you updated Hibernate to the latest version 5.4.32/5.5.7? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: yes, I'm currently having the version at 5.4.32